# Can't add the exec option to my data partition in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash, partitioning, executable

I'm using an HDD as a external drive, it has 3 partitions and one of them is for my Ubuntu Documents. I'm trying to compile my programs and it gives me the msg:

> bash: ./qt-opencv-multithreaded: Permission denied

I read that this issue can be fixed by changing the exec option, this is how my partition looks like right now:

> /dev/sda3 on /media/storage type fuseblk
>   (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)

I tried to run this command:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/storage/
```

But it gives me this error:

> Remounting is not supported at present. You have to umount volume and
>   then mount it once again.

I'm kinda new to Ubuntu, and I am not really sure how to do umount and mount thing, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*umount*-ing is as simple as:

```
umount /media/storage
```

(If that doesn't work, then run the same thing with `sudo`: `sudo umount /media/storage`)

Following the instructions, after the `umount` you could try to `mount` again:

```
sudo mount -o rw,exec,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096 /dev/sda3 /media/storage
```

But... I think your life will be easier to copy the files you want to compile to a local disk and compile and run there.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will just compile locally, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a external Disk .. you may not execute in that..

better copy program in your virtual memory i mean your root system..  Then it will work.

and for mounting..

try to do:

umount /dev/sda3

then 
mount /dev/sda3  /mnt

- intead of mnt you can use any other location you want.